# How can i look for a not specific value from one worksheet in another worksheet in Excel?

Tags: excel, vba

i am trying to program a macro that i can use on a random value in one worksheet, and the macro is supposed to look for it in another worksheet, go 11 cells to the left and copy the Value in that cell back to the first worksheet, next to the random value.

my macro so far:

```vb
Sub Makro3()

    Selection.Copy
    
    Sheets("Messgeräte").Select
    
    
    Cells.Find(What:=***thats where i dont know what to put***, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:= _
        xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext _
        , MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
        
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, -11).Select
    
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    
    Selection.Copy
    
    Sheets("Lagermedien").Select
    
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
    
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    
End Sub
```

please dont judge, i am new to this :)

the problem for me is that it is always new values and new cells. Otherwise i could just record a macro.

In the best case scenario this would work with more than one Value, means: the program looks for the random Value in the second worksheet and finds a couple of different cells that all have that very same Value and copies them to the first worksheet.

Comment: Since you're writing to `Lagermedien`, let's call it `Dest`, and the other one `Source`. Why would you want to write the results for just one cell instead of for all of the cells? They are most certainly in **one** column (maybe **one** row). In the `Source`, you **don't** want to search the whole worksheet, not even the used range. You most often want to search one (perhaps more) **known** columns. Try to clarify where the various data are located e.g. the lookup values are in `Dest` column `A` and I want to write to the right. The lookup range is in column `L` of Source and I need `A` etc.

Comment: i didnt quite know how to express my problem. You got it right though. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Multi VBA Lookup (Find)

- This will loop through the cells of column `A` (`dlCol`) in `Destination` to find each 'partial' (`xlPart`) occurrence of the cell value, in column `M` (`slCol`) of `Source` to write the corresponding values of column `A` (`svCol`) in `Source` to columns (`.Offset(, cOffset)`) of the corresponding row in `Destination`, starting with column `B` (`dvCol`).
- Carefully adjust the values in the constants section. Note that there is no `Undo`.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub MultiLookupFind()

    ' Source
    Const sName As String = "Messgeräte" ' Worksheet Name
    Const sfRow As Long = 2 ' First Row
    Const slCol As String = "M" ' Lookup Column
    Const svCol As String = "A" ' Value Column
    ' Destination
    Const dName As String = "Lagermedien" ' Worksheet Name
    Const dfRow As Long = 2 ' First Row
    Const dlCol As String = "A" ' Lookup Column
    Const dvCol As String = "B" ' Value Column
    
    ' Workbook
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    ' Source
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Worksheets(sName)
    Dim slRow As Long: slRow = sws.Cells(sws.Rows.Count, slCol).End(xlUp).Row
    If slRow < sfRow Then Exit Sub ' no data
    Dim srCount As Long: srCount = slRow - sfRow + 1
    Dim slrg As Range: Set slrg = sws.Cells(sfRow, slCol).Resize(srCount)
    
    ' Destination
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Worksheets(dName)
    Dim dlRow As Long: dlRow = dws.Cells(dws.Rows.Count, dlCol).End(xlUp).Row
    If dlRow < dfRow Then Exit Sub ' no data
    Dim drCount As Long: drCount = dlRow - dfRow + 1
    Dim dlrg As Range: Set dlrg = dws.Cells(dfRow, dlCol).Resize(drCount)

    ' Loop
    Dim dCell As Range
    Dim sCell As Range
    Dim dString As String
    Dim cOffset As Long
    Dim FirstAddress As String
    For Each dCell In dlrg.Cells
        Set sCell = Nothing
        cOffset = 0
        dString = CStr(dCell.Value)
        Set sCell = slrg.Find(dString, slrg.Cells(srCount), xlFormulas, xlPart)
        If Not sCell Is Nothing Then
            FirstAddress = sCell.Address
            Do
                dCell.EntireRow.Columns(dvCol).Offset(, cOffset).Value _
                    = sCell.EntireRow.Columns(svCol).Value
                Set sCell = slrg.FindNext(sCell)
                cOffset = cOffset + 1
            Loop Until sCell.Address = FirstAddress
        End If
    Next dCell

End Sub
```

Comment: thanks, what do you mean by ´no data? do i have to fill in anything?

Comment: It means e.g. if `slRow` results in `1`, that there is no data from the 2nd row to the bottom-most row (it is assumed that the bottom-most row is empty). There is nothing to look up (search for) then. Also, the code would fail on the upcoming `Resize` since `1 - 2 + 1 = 0` which it cannot handle.

Answer (score 3):

This will handle multiple matches:

```vb
Sub Makro3()

    Dim f As Range, c As Range, allMatches As Collection, i As Long
    
    Set c = Selection.Cells(1) 'only want one cell, so take first if >1 selected
    
    Set allMatches = FindAll(Sheets("Messgeräte").Cells, c.Value) 'find all matches
    i = 0
    For Each f In allMatches 'loop over any matched cells
        i = i + 1
        f.offset(0, 11).Copy c.Offset(0, i)
    Next f
End Sub

'Find all (partial) matches in a range, and return them as a collection of cells
Public Function FindAll(rng As Range, val As String) As Collection
    Dim rv As New Collection, f As Range
    Dim addr As String

    Set f = rng.Find(what:=val, after:=rng.Cells(rng.Cells.CountLarge), _
                     LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                     SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False)
    If Not f Is Nothing Then addr = f.Address()

    Do Until f Is Nothing
        rv.Add f
        Set f = rng.FindNext(after:=f)
        If f.Address() = addr Then Exit Do
    Loop
    Set FindAll = rv
End Function
```

Comment: First of all thank you for the code.   regarding the second part: yes thats right i didnt think that through. Multiple values would be next to the found value. I guess it would be for the second found value: ActiveCell.Offset(0,2), for the third ActiveCell.offset(0,3) and so on.

Comment: it didnt work quite. It found the values in the other worksheet but couldnt copy the Value in the cell that is 11 cells to the left.

Comment: My mistake - missed the offset.  See edit above.

Comment: So my Excel crashed twice using this code hahaha. And norw it shows instead of the values it should show, the values it copied in the beginning from the first cell and some of the cells, where the values from the second sheet are supposed to be show #REF! Did i do anything wrong?

Comment: @JuSchmid: To see an older version of the post, you can follow the link [edited ... ago](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68857924/revisions) located between `Flag` and `answered ... ago` above the comments.

Comment: I have no idea what your data looks like, but you should be aware that a partial match Find() on a whole sheet could potentially find *many* hits, particularly if (for example) you just search for "a".  Maybe you need to narrow your search area, and put a lower limit on the length of the search term?